# Codeigniter: How to implement inner join in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to know how can I query inner joins in mongodb? I have this `users` and `payments` table. I only want to display records that `users` has `payments` if not, do not include it in the result. So far, I only got left join like results.

Here is my code:

```
$getData=[
  [
    '$match' => ['profile_status'=> 'buyer']
  ],
  [
    '$project'=>[
      '_id'             =>  ['$toString' => '$_id'],
      'profile_image'   =>  '$profile_image',
      'full_name'       =>  '$full_name',
      'profile_status' => '$profile_status'
    ]
  ],
  [
    '$lookup' => [
      'from' => 'payment_details',
      'let' => [
        'user_id' =>  ['$toString' => '$_id']
      ],
      'pipeline' => [
          [
            '$match' => [
              '$expr' => ['$eq' => ['$buyer_id','$$user_id']]
            ]
          ],
          [
            '$project' => [
              '_id'             =>  ['$toString' => '$_id'],
              'price'   =>  '$price'
            ]
          ],
        ],
      'as' => 'paymentData'
    ]
  ]
];
$getresult=  $db->users->aggregate($getData);
$getfinalresult=  iterator_to_array($getresult);
```

This code returns `users` data even `paymentData` is empty, I only want `users` that has `paymentData`. Im using PHP/Codeigniter 3.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using a library in order to connect to mongo? If so, which one are you using?

Comment: Hi Sir @ManuelGuzman, PHP mongodb library